# New Google Calendar (2017) Quick Add

Tags: google-calendar

In the old Google Calendar, I was able to create a new event by clicking on a day and typing both the description and time together in one field, like "Dr. Appointment 10am-11am", and it would parse that out and set the time accordingly. this feature is called Quick Add.

In the new Google Calendar interface (2017), I can't get that to work. If I type the same thing now, the whole string "Dr. Appointment 10am-11am" goes into the description, and it makes it an "all day" event.

Is there still a way to do this, or did Google remove the Quick Add feature?

Answer (score 15):

Quick Add isn't available for/built into the new Calendar, but does work with a Chrome extension called *Google Calendar* (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-calendar-by-google/gmbgaklkmjakoegficnlkhebmhkjfich?hl=en)

[image: Chrome extension for Calendar quick add]

Comment: Thank god for the extension.  Ridiculous that you'd need an extension for basic functionality.

Comment: But aren't they doing away with extensions in chrome also? https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/google-removes-chrome-apps-from-chrome-web-store/
So this won't work either soon?

Comment: @nealmcb they are not killing chrome extensions. They are removing a very specific piece of functionality that almost no one used.

Comment: Seems like Google's on a killing spree against all useful functionality from everything ever.

Comment: [Quick Add has issues, according to that developer](https://github.com/manastungare/google-calendar-crx/wiki/Quick-Add-Bugs); I'd imagine the fact that it's no longer a feature would mean that any such outstanding bugs will never get fixed. To me, that means that Quick Add is dead and should be avoided. [Adding via the Google Search search field, as in this other answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/118185), seems to me the better choice for that reason.

Comment: This extension, unfortunately, is no longer functional. I'm still looking for a substitute!

Answer (score 11):

The workaround is to type the event in Google search, e.g.

- "add to calendar some description tomorrow at 1PM"

then click on *Create event*.

Source: https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/calendar/CIwo3Ch-aTk/AcAtErUNBQAJ

[image: quick add to Google Calendar]

Comment: This no longer works.  Just searches for events with those words.

Comment: @JonathanCross I've tested and they still work. Are you logged in?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I didn't read carefully.  I was trying to add from **Google Calendar**'s search, not _Google_ search.

Comment: This appears to no longer work.

Answer (score 4):

Google removed that functionality in the new Calendar.

You can send feedback by clicking the gear icon > 'Send Feedback'.

You can also vote up or comment on the support forum posts here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/CIwo3Ch-aTk;context-place=topicsearchin/calendar/quick$20add%7Csort:date

Answer (score 3):

1. Click the *date* (top of the column where "all day" events are located) for the specific date that you want to add an event.
2. Enter time range & event name (i.e. **7:00am-5:30pm Work** or **Work 7:00am-5:30pm**)
3. Click **Save**

Comment: This is a partial workaround. Still can't click one place no matter where I am and get it to intelligently create an event for a date in the future. That is, now have to navigate to the day/days of the event. Thankfully that's keyboardable, but it still requires clicking the day. Mixed-mode input is okay for games, but not so good for productivity, and not as fast as Quick Add.

Answer (score 1):

I tried it again today and it worked! It seems Google heard our cries.

For example, clicking a day and typing "something at 5pm" now creates an event called "something" at 5pm in Google Calendar, as it used to do.

Comment: Confirming that it worked for me also. I typed in "10pm Do blahblah" and it created event titled "Do blahblah" at 10pm on the day I clicked

Comment: This only seems to work only for very simple events on a pre-selected date.

Comment: Thanks but this is a horribly poor substitute. I used to be able to type  "q12/4 13:00 meet jack at 123 main st<enter>" and get an appointment added with a location. Now I have to use my mouse to set the date and time. I can type a single phrase with a date and time and destination far quicker than I can enter them with a mouse.

Comment: This only works for the same day event. "something Monday at 5pm" no longer works.

Comment: With the new system, I am unable to write "Meet with Bob 30 minutes" and have it create a 30 minute appointment in the time slot I selected. That was such a great feature - just gone apparently.

Comment: This only works on the same day. They really didn't fix it.

Answer (score -3):

If you type it with time in front, as "10am Dr. Appointment" it still works, but only for a one hour item. Can't seem to get a range of time to work, nor recognition of location by using "at" or "@" which used to work as well.

Comment: I just tried that and it didn't work for me. I typed in "7pm Stuff", and it created an all-day appointment called "7pm Stuff".